# Common pattern for populating select list data in Backbone views?

Tags: javascript, forms, backbone.js, html-select

My Backbone app has several views containing forms with text inputs select fields, and checkboxes. The select fields should be populated using data from my API. A given select field may be reused in multiple different forms.

What's a commonly-used approach for populating these dropdowns? Here's a solution I've rigged together...**is there a more common approach?**

A reusable select field which populates itself...app/views/shared/location_selection.js:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'backbone',
  'app/views/base',
  'app/collections/location'
], function($, Backbone, BaseView, LocationCollection) {
  'use strict';

  return BaseView.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
      this.options = options || {};
      this.options.id = this.options.id || 'location';
      this.options.showBlank = typeof this.options.showBlank != 'undefined' ? this.options.showBlank : false;

      this.collection = new LocationCollection();
    },

    render: function() {
      this.setElement('<select id="' + this.options.id + '"></select>');

      var self = this;
      this.collection.fetch({
        success: function() {
          if (self.options.showBlank) {
            self.$el.append('<option></option');
          }

          self.collection.each(function(model) {
            self.$el.append('<option value="' + model.get('id') + '">' + model.get('name') + '</option>');
          });
        }
      });

      return this;
    }
  });
});
```

And a snippet from another view which uses that view:

```
render: function() {
  this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

  var locationSelectionView = new LocationSelectionView({ showBlank: !this.model.get('id') });
  this.$('.location').append(locationSelectionView.render().el);

  return this;
},
```

And the form template:

```
<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="imei">IMEI</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="imei" value="{{data.imei}}" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group location">
    <label for="location">Location</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input id="master" type="checkbox"{{#if master}} checked="checked"{{/if}} /> Master</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have separate templates for both your item view and collection view you can do it this way:

```
var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'option',
    initialize:function(){        
        this.template= _.template($('#menu_item_view').html());    
    },    
    render:function(){        
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));        
        return this;        
    }
});

var CollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'select',
    initialize:function(){        
        this.collection = new ItemCollection();            
        this.collection.on('sync',this.render,this);            
        this.collection.fetch();
    },    
    render:function(){        
        _.each(this.collection.models,function( item ){            
            this.$el.append(new ItemView({model:item}).render().el );        
        },this);      
        return this;        
    }
});
```

Edit: just as a note, before Backbone 1.0 when you called fetch it use to trigger 'reset' but now it triggers 'sync' unless you write fetch({reset:true}). So depending on the version of Backbone you are running, be aware of that.

Comment: @redconservatory, is writing this.$el.html(this.collection.map(function(model){return new ItemView({model:item}).render().el;}); generally better?

Comment: Hmm.  Interesting.  Seems a little heavy handed to instantiate a new view object for each option, though. And it takes the html out of a template.